# Reacquiring a Pennsylvania driver’s license

Tags: usa, driving-license

I had to surrender my Pennsylvania license when I acquired my Norwegian driver’s license. If I move back what is required to get my Pennsylvania license back.?

Comment: I do not know, but the answer might depend on the expiration date of your original license.

Answer (score 1):

You can go to the DMV and begin the renewal process the next time you're in Pennsylvania. You will require your social security card, and some proof of a Pennsylvania address (A few pieces of mail which comes in your name to whichever PA address you're using). I did this last summer and I did not have to provide my old PA license. You can't do the 'online renewal' and you may need to go through the process of claiming a lost license, but you should be able to go to the DMV and do the whole thing in a few hours.

Whether you have to go through the 'lost license' or 'license renewal' process is up to your local DMV (the website even tells you to go there and ask). You won't be able to do the process online, but as long as you have all the documentation, you should be fine to do everything in person.

There is a rule which states that your license cannot have expired more than 6 months in the past, but it was not being enforced when I went through the process recently. I hadn't had a PA license in about 10 years. However, YMMV.

https://www.dmv.org/pa-pennsylvania/renew-license.php